# flask form.data values not updated on submit

Tags: python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms, flask-restful

I have a form that I dynamically populate the values of using the .default method.

Like this:

```
for i, item in enumerate(staff):
    if item.id == "csrf_token" or item.id == "submitstaff":
        continue
    item.default = stafftable[0][i]
    staff.process()
```

I also have also used this form without that process and it works. However, when I use it after doing this process it always takes the default values not allowing the user to update the values anymore. FOr example if I display the form agian and attempt to change the values of a field it will take the .default field set by the process not the input.

Form:

```
class Staff(FlaskForm):
    staffid = StringField(
        validators=[DataRequired(message="Staff Id Field can not be left blank")]
    )
    Firstname = StringField(
        validators=[DataRequired(message="Firstname Field can not be left blank")]
    )
    LastName = StringField(
        validators=[DataRequired(message="LastName Field can not be left blank")]
    )
    ProjectRole = StringField(
        validators=[DataRequired(message="ProjectRole Field can not be left blank")]
    )
    YearsOfExperience = FloatField(
        validators=[
            DataRequired(message="Years of experience Field can not be left blank")
        ]
    )
    Organisation = SelectField(
        "Organisations",
        choices=[
            ("1","1"),
            ("1","1"),
            ("1","1"),
        ],
    )
    OfficeLocation = StringField(
        validators=[DataRequired(message="Office location Field can not be left blank")]
    )
    Discipline = SelectField(
        "Discipline",
        choices=[
            ("Geotechnics", "Geotechnics"),
            ("Civil", "Civl"),
            ("Digital", "Digital"),
            ("Project Management", "Project Management"),
        ],
    )
    KeyPersonName = SelectField(choices=[("No","No"),("Yes","Yes")])
    BatchNo = StringField(
        validators=[DataRequired(message="BatchNo Field can not be left blank")]
    )
    ProjectStatus = StringField(
        validators=[DataRequired(message="ProjectStatus Field can not be left blank")]
    )
    Booking = StringField(
        validators=[DataRequired(message="Booking Field can not be left blank")]
    )
    TasksEarlyDeliverables = TextAreaField(
        validators=[
            DataRequired(
                message="Tasks and early deliverables Field can not be left blank"
            )
        ]
    )

    requester = StringField()
    package = StringField()
    PercentoftimeS1 =  FloatField()
    HourlyRate = FloatField()
    PercentoftimeS2 = FloatField()

    submitstaff = SubmitField(label="Submit", validators=[DataRequired()])
```

Answer (score 0):

So after some research, I found out that using .process was causing it to not work properly. However with the code above without using .process it wouldn't show the data on the webpage.

The solution to showing the data was actually to use .data instead of .default.